# Error while applying aggreagtion on a null values column in spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I am trying apply apply a aggregation on amountpaid column where it has some null' as well.
    What I have done is I made it as 0 using when other.
    After that I have applied aggregation and ran show on particular DF. 
    But still it is throwing `NullPointer Exception`.
    I am not where I am missing. If someone helps that would be great.

```
transactionId|customerId|itemId|amountPaid|amountpaid1|
+-------------+----------+------+----------+-----------+
|          111|         1|     1|     100.0|      100.0|
|          112|         2|     2|     505.0|      505.0|
|          113|         3|  null|      null|        0.0|
|          114|         4|     4|     600.0|      600.0|
|          115|         1|     2|     510.0|      510.0|
|          116|         1|     2|     520.0|      520.0|
|          117|         1|  null|      null|        0.0|
|          118|         1|     2|    4400.0|     4400.0|
|          119|         2|     3|    3300.0|     3300.0|
|          120|         1|     2|    1500.0|     1500.0|
|          121|         1|     4|    2500.0|     2500.0|
|          122|         1|  null|      null|        0.0|
|          123|         1|     4|    1100.0|     1100.0|
|          124|         1|     1|    5100.0|     5100.0|
+-------------+----------+------+----------+-----------+

val salesDF = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("file:///home/cloudera/projects/spark-sql/src/main/resources/sales-error.csv")

val defaultDF = salesDF.withColumn("amountpaid",when(col("amountpaid").isNullll,0).otherwise(col("amountpaid")))

val aggDF = filterDF.groupBy("customerId").agg(sum("amountpaid1").as("total")).show
```

Comment: try to use coalesce function instead to default it to 0 if the data is null.

Comment: Still I am getting an error as 19/11/26 06:31:40 ERROR Executor: Managed memory leak detected; size = 67371008 bytes, TID = 6
19/11/26 06:31:40 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6)
java.lang.NullPointerException